# Caching service HTTP calls in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement caching of HTTP requests within my service, here is a snippet of my code:

```
//...
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishReplay';
//...

@Injectable()
export class FundsService {

    /**
     * @var {String} URL of funds api
     */
    private baseUrl = 'http://budget.vagrant/api/funds';

    /**
     * @var {Array} Cache of last getFunds request
     */
    private funds : Observable<any> = null;

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private router : Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all existing comments
     * @param {boolean} useCache Will use the service's cache array when true
     */
    getFunds(useCache : boolean = true) : Observable<Fund[]> {

        // add authorization header with jwt token
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.getToken()
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
console.log("this.funds = ", this.funds) // <-- every time, null
        if (this.funds === null) {
            this.funds = this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
                .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                .do(funds => console.log('fetched funds', funds))
                .publishReplay(1)
                .refCount();
        }
console.log("this.funds = ", this.funds) // <-- every time, has value from http call - but subsequent calls it'll be null again 
        return this.funds;
    }
    //...
```

I've been following along this tutorial btw - http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0

I can't understand why this.funds is reset to null each time. I'm not refreshing the browser, just using Angular Router to navigate "pages" (components/templates), I assume that FundsService is injected into each new component every time so when I reload this component it'll have the same singleton instance as before, right? So then this.funds would be set from the previous http call, and not re-init as null.

Here is my component using the service:

```
export class FundsListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private fundsService: FundsService,
        private loadingService : LoadingService) { }

    funds: Fund[];

    /**
    * Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound
    * properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
    * Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().
    */
    ngOnInit() : void {

        this.fundsService.getFunds()
            .subscribe(
                funds => {
                    return this.funds = funds
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

Comment: *"when I reload this component it'll have the same singleton instance as before, right?"* - that depends on where you define that provider. If you define it at the module level: yes. If you define it at the component level: no, they get a different instance each.

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you. That really helped.